# If you are using "vi.mock" factory, make sure there are no top level variables inside

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mysql2, vitest, kysely

I'm new to testing and would like to learn how to mock the `mysql2` database as an instance of `Kysely` with `vitest`. I've been following a thread provided from [GitHub](https://github.com/kysely-org/kysely/issues/801), but I encountered the error as the title it says:

database.ts

```
import * as dotenv              from "dotenv";
import { type DB }              from "../types/schema.types";
import { createPool, }          from "mysql2";
import { Kysely, MysqlDialect } from "kysely";
dotenv.config();

export const dialect = new MysqlDialect({
  pool: createPool({
    database: `${process.env.DATABASE}`,
    host: `${process.env.DATABASE_HOST}`,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT as unknown as number,
    user: `${process.env.USER}`,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    waitForConnections: true,
    multipleStatements: true,
    charset: "utf8mb4",
    connectionLimit: `${process.env.DATABASE_CONNECTION_LIMIT}` as unknown as number,
    queueLimit: 0,
  }),
})

const db = new Kysely<DB>({ dialect });
export default db;
```

sample.spec.ts

```
import { it, vi, expect } from "vitest";
import db from "../database/database";
import { DB } from "../types/schema.types";
import { Kysely, MysqlDialect } from "kysely";

// Test case
it("Get user count", async () => {
  const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => ({ query: vi.fn() }));
  
  // Mocking database module
  vi.mock("../database/database", async (importOriginal) => {
    const actualModule = await importOriginal<typeof import("../database/database")>();
    return {
      ...actualModule,
      __esModule: true,
      ownerDb: new Kysely<DB>({
        dialect: new MysqlDialect({ pool: vi.fn() }),
      }),
    };
  });

  mocks.query.mockResolvedValue({ rows: [{ count: 1 }] });

  const query = db
    .selectFrom("users")
    .select((eb) => eb.fn.count<number>("users.user_id").as("count"));

  const { count } = await db
    .selectNoFrom((eb) => eb.fn.coalesce(query, eb.lit(0)).as("count"))
    .executeTakeFirstOrThrow();

  expect(count).toBe(1);
```

full error:
[image]

Comment: post the full error

Comment: Can we see the error message, and what file/line triggered it?

Comment: the error was coming from `const actualModule = await importOriginal<typeof import("../database/database")>();` at `sample.spec.ts`. Sorry, I included just now the full error from the post. thank you

Answer (score 1):

From [the vi.mock documentation](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock)...

> vi.mock is hoisted (in other words, moved) to top of the file. It means that whenever you write it (be it inside beforeEach or test), it will actually be called before that.

That means what's really run is this:

```
import { it, vi, expect } from "vitest";

// Mocking database module
vi.mock("../database/database", async (importOriginal) => {
  const actualModule = await importOriginal<typeof import("../database/database")>();
  return {
    ...actualModule,
    __esModule: true,
    ownerDb: new Kysely<DB>({
      dialect: new MysqlDialect({ pool: vi.fn() }),
    }),
  };
});

import db from "../database/database";
import { DB } from "../types/schema.types";
import { Kysely, MysqlDialect } from "kysely";

// Test case
it("Get user count", async () => {
  const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => ({ query: vi.fn() }));
```

The block passed to `vi.mock` cannot see `DB`. You can use `vi.hoisted` on the import. Then the import will be hoisted along with the call to `vi.mock`.

```
import { it, vi, expect } from "vitest";
import db from "../database/database";
import { Kysely, MysqlDialect } from "kysely";
const { DB } = vi.hoisted(() => await import('../types/schema.types'));
```

See [A Practical Guide to Mocking Svelte Stores with Vitest](https://bentilling.com/a-practical-guide-to-mocking-svelte-stores-with-vitest).

---

However, hoisting makes the code very difficult to understand and `vi.mock` is loaded with caveats. Consider using [`vi.doMock`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-domock) instead. Note that you will have to dynamically import ../database/database.

Comment: @peter I tried following the site you have provided but it didn't work out for me. What I did is used your suggestion using`vi.doMock` but what I notice it gets the actual total number of data in my `users` table. Does it really used the mocked one and it is alright? Here is the code: https://imgur.com/a/PUremDI

Comment: @AlmightyDee 1) Your call to `vi.dbMock` has no factory. 2) `imports` are also hoisted, so `vi.dbMock` happens after the imports. You have to dynamically load the import after `vi.dbMock` as in [the example in the documentation](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-domock).